# Jsoup selector on RSS <link> tag returns empty string with .text() method

Tags: java, rss, jsoup

I'm using [jsoup](/questions/tagged/jsoup) to parse an [rss](/questions/tagged/rss) feed using [java](/questions/tagged/java). I'm having problems getting a result when trying to select the first `<link>` element in the document.

When I use `title.text()` I get an expected result with this code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();
Element title = doc.select("rss channel title").first();
System.out.println(title.text()); // print the blog title...
```

However, `link.text()` doesn't work the same way:

```
Element link = doc.select("rss channel link").first();
System.out.println(link.text()); // prints empty string
```

When I inspect `doc.select("rss channel link")` the `Element link` object is populated but the `.println()` statement is just an empty string.

What makes `.select("rss channel link")` so dang special that I can't figure out how to use it?

Edit: The RSS response begins like this:

> ```
>    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>     <rss>
>     <channel>
>     <title>The Blog Title</title>
>     <link>http://www.the.blog/category</link>
> ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your rss feed is XML, not HTML. For this to work, you must tell JSoup to use its XMLParser. This will work:

```
String rss = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
  +"<rss><channel>"
  +  "<title>The Blog Title</title>"
  +  "<link>http://www.the.blog/category</link>"
  +"</channel></rss>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(rss, "", Parser.xmlParser());

Element link = doc.select("rss channel link").first();
System.out.println(link.text()); // prints empty string
```

Explanation:

The link tag in HTML follows a different format and Jsoup tries to interpret the `<link>` of your rss as such html tag.

Comment: Oh neat, thanks for the clarification.  Just a heads up,  you can parse and get in the same line using a Jsoup connect().   `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(RSS_URL).parser(Parser.xmlParser()).get();`

Answer (score 1):

Refer [here](http://jsoup.org/news/release-1.6.2). Jsoup added this XmlParser.

```
try {
    String xml = "<rss></rss><channel></channel><link>http://www.the.blog/category</link><title>The Blog Title</title>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser());

    Element title = doc.select("title").first();
    System.out.println(title.text());

    Element link = doc.select("link").first();
    System.out.println(link.text());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: the xml you put in the string is not the same that the OP tries to parse. ```<rss></rss>...```

Comment: @luksch I just want to illustrate how XmlParser works in Jsoup. I knew that the String is not the same.

Comment: cool, yep, thanks for your help!  I've got a working solution now :-)  though technically luksh was first, so he gets the answer vote