# Unable to get RSS feed link using jsoup

Tags: android-studio, rss, jsoup

I am trying to build an rss feed reader app. I am fetching the rss link and parsing it using jsoup. I am getting the rss feeds of sites like wired, mashable, whackyideas, techcrunch, entrepreneur and other similar sites. But, when I am trying sites like nytimes, bbc, cnn or other news sites, I am unable to fetch the rss link. I think the problem is with the below mentioned code. Can anybody help me out with this?

```
public String getRSSLinkFromURL(String url) {
// RSS url
String rss_url = null;

try {
    // Using JSoup library to parse the html source code
    org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    // finding rss links which are having link[type=application/rss+xml]
    org.jsoup.select.Elements links = doc
            .select("link[type=application/rss+xml]");

    Log.d("No of RSS links found", " " + links.size());

    // check if urls found or not
    if (links.size() > 0) {
        rss_url = links.get(0).attr("href").toString();
    } else {
        // finding rss links which are having link[type=application/rss+xml]
        org.jsoup.select.Elements links1 = doc
                .select("link[type=application/rss+xml]");
        if(links1.size() > 0){
            rss_url = links1.get(0).attr("href").toString();
        }
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have also tried using "atom + xml" in place of "rss+xml", but getting the same result.

Edit: I have modified the code in the following manner and I am getting more number of sites opening, which were not opening earlier. But I am still not getting sites like " www.BBC.com" and "www.timesofindia.indiatimes.com" .  I would be grateful if anyone can help me out

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36")
    .timeout(12000)
    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
    .get();
```

Comment: Please give at least one of the feed addresses that you tried that do not work the way you expect. Also, is there an error, or what happens. Any stacktrace?

Comment: @luksch Links like bbc.com, nytimes.com are not working. There is no errors, it is just showing "no links found" ie it is unable to fetch the RSS feed link

Comment: To me, bbc.com front page source doesn't contain any rss links. Times of India makes a redirect to an ad, you should handle redirects too as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24907808/jsoup-get-redirected-url

Comment: @janih I followed the same, but it is still not getting rss links. Sites like gizmodo.com and timesofindia, cnn are not getting captured.

Comment: Did you set the `followRedirects(true)`? I think if you can get the redirects working and if the pages really contain rss links, then your code should work. Also it is important to change the user agent, but you did that already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jsoup selector on RSS <link> tag returns empty string with .text() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260549/jsoup-selector-on-rss-link-tag-returns-empty-string-with-text-method)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the quotes around "application/rss+xml": `"link[type="application/rss+xml"]"`